# Check numbering of chapters and sections using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How can I properly check numbering of chapters and sections using regex? Input document could be commonly formatted dissertation or a book. I would like to separate each chapter/section number and their names/titles with the below example input avoiding fake inputs. The problem probably is "dot" character on the regex side. It might be special character. Any suggestions there in order to fix the issue ?

```
import re

testContent = ["1. Name Chapter Name", "1.1. Section name abcdefg", 
               "1.1.1. Subsection tests", "1.2. aaaaaaaaaa", "2. Chapter 2", 
               "12 ml fake input", "section 3.3 fake input"]

seperated = {}
for line in testContent:
    match = re.search(r'^[1-9.]+', line)
    if match:
        rest  = re.sub(match.group(), '', line)
        seperated.update({match.group() : rest})
print(seperated)
```

Result is:

```
{'1.': ' Name Chapter Name', '1.1.': ' Section name abcdefg', '1.1.1.': ' Subsection tests', '1.2.': ' aaaaaaaaaa', '2.': ' Chapter 2', '12': ' ml fake input'}
```

Comment: can you provide the desired output structure?

Comment: The only issue on the result is the "12 ml fake input" which is flagged as a fake input already. Because it does not have "." after section or chapter number. I know this is not perfect segmentation strategy but it could be alright for me if the code eliminate the fake input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
for test in testContent:
  match = re.search(r'^([1-9]\.)+',test)
  print(match)
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='1.'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1.1.'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='1.1.1.'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1.2.'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='2.'>
None
None
```

fake inputs excluded...

Comment: You should use raw string(`r''`) because it contains `\ `. Or `'^([1-9]\\.)+'`

Comment: I dont think so it is the answer because it catches "6.1 section bla bla" as well. However, this is also not the case. Because as it is described each chapter and section numbering has to have "." at the end in order to capture it.

Comment: "6.1 section bla bla" is also fake input but can not excluded with your suggested regex.

Comment: @ozturkib Simply add an expression matching a space to the end of Strange's expression; e.g. r'^([1-9]\.)+[ \t]' to make sure the engine does not give up any of the numbers.

Comment: @oriberu Thanks for the answer you are absolutely right. Space in the bracket is fine but why do you also place "\t" there, probably for tab character?

Comment: @ozturkib Exactly. If there can't be a tab in that position, simply remove the character class and just use a single space instead.